# socket.io rooms repeating same message per client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using rooms to send a 'private' message to a client and it works however the message being sent is duplicated by the number of clients I have and I believe this is because of my `.on('message')` since this is still triggering for every client but only emitting to the correct client (but multiple times..)

server

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket {
    socket.on('join', function(data)
    {
        console.log('enter');
        socket.join(data.user);
});

var rClient =   redis.createClient();
rClient.subscribe('messagex');

rClient.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    io.in(message.user).emit('messagex', {content: message.content});
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    rClient.quit();
});
```

});

receiver client

```
<script>
var username = prompt("test");
var socket  =   io.connect('http://localhost:8100');
socket.emit('join', {user: username});

socket.on('messagex', function(data) {
    $('#messages').append('<p>' + data.content + '</p>');
});
```

So I have 3 clients (each with different users/rooms open) at the receiver page and I send a message from the sender to say user user1, then I will only receive the message on user1 client but it will receive 3 of the same message each time and the number of times duplicated seems to be the number of clients I have..

Comment: why you use 'subscribe'? simply broadcast the message to that particular user using a room

Comment: i'm using redis and publishing from php. I don't emit to the server from the client when sending 'the' message

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
subscribe.unsubscribe(channel);
```

when connection disconnect  unsubscribe

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket {
socket.on('join', function(data)
{
    console.log('enter');
    socket.join(data.user);
});

var rClient =   redis.createClient();
rClient.subscribe('messagex');

rClient.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    io.in(message.user).emit('messagex', {content: message.content});
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {

rClient.unsubscribe('messagex'); 
  rClient.quit();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using two channel at same time redis and socket.io, You have to make single channel i.e. socket.io only then there is no need make redis channel means no need to add pub/sub method when you transferring data through emit/on.